# No results when using Social Tag Refiner

Tags: search, tagging, refiner

When clicking on a SocialTag refiner in SharePoint Enterprise search, the search can not find any results. The content is clearly there since the refiner is there and I get results in the initial search before refining.

The refiner clicked has the following hyperlink.
results.aspx?k=test&r=socialtagId%3D45cca958%2Dedb4%2D4cab%2Db10f%2D2285b379c300

Any ideas what is wrong or has experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Please check
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepoint2010setup/thread/1485e82a-49f6-44d7-92e1-649be85352ad

"You can set the search path for MySites by going to Central Admin -> Mange Service Applications -> Click on your User Profile Service Application.
From here under the MySite Heading the first option is Setup My Sites. Once you click on this the first section is where you can set the Search Center for My Sites. You can also configure the scopes for People and Documents."

I had to reset index and reboot the server indeed.